# Contact Form with drop-down subject (bonus: auto-selected based on GET/POST)

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, webforms, emails

I have a number of services on my site and I want them to all direct to the contact form. Now, this is where it gets tricky- I want the subject to be a dropdown selection of all services provided and, if possible [bonus], based on the link clicked (GET/POST).

**Alternatively:**
I would also be open to a contact-form jquery popup modal box that I could tailor for specific services.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `hook_node_view()` to pre-select default value of webform component on the base of referer.

```
function yourmodule_node_view($node, $view_mode){
    if($node->nid == [nid of webform]){
            global $base_path;
            $referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
            $start = strpos($referer, $base_path) + strlen($base_path);
            $ref_local_path = substr($referer, $start);
            switch($ref_local_path){
                    case 'service_1_path':
                            $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted']['<component_name>']['#default_value'] = 'option_1';
                    break;
                    case 'service_2_path':
                            $node->content['webform']['#form']['submitted']['<component_name>']['#default_value'] = 'option_2';
                    break;
            }
    }
...
```

If you are looking to do it via JS/JQuery that is another solution.